# Windows 10 Doesn't Detect Hard Drive Anymore - How to Recover

Tags: hardware-failure

My computer has an SSD and a HD. SSD contains Windows 10 while my HD has my programs and documents. When I turn on my computer, it takes about 5 minutes to load into Windows where it then freezes. I am unable to perform any tasks in Windows. Previously, CrystalDiskInfo has reported that my HD has bad sectors. I unplugged my HD and I am able to successfully load Windows 10.

My problem is that I need the data and applications from my failed HD. I would like to clone my failing HD onto a new HD, then plug it into my computer so Windows will function normally as before (ie - my applications will still be stored, settings and documents will remain the same). What sort of steps can I take to clone my drive?

**UPDATE:**

I have taken a look at the linked resource ([How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device/241822)) but I don't think it helps me in my situation. I do not think I have a mechanical issue as I do not hear any weird noises coming from my hard drive. Furthermore, CrystalDiskInfo has reported that I have bad sectors. To recover from corruption or bad sectors, the linked resource says to get direct access to the data. Right now Windows freezes when I plug in my hard drive. How do I gain direct access to the data?

Looks like EaseUS allows to clone failing HDD/SSD that has bad sectors. My question is how do I gain access to the data in my failed HDD?

Comment: It is a little late to clone your HDD, if it has already has bad sectors, the time that needed to be done was before the HDD failed.

Comment: @Ramhound I found that EaseUS can clone with bad sectors

Comment: Just because you don't hear a noise, doesn't mean, your HdD hasn't already failed.  Out of all the mechanical hdd that have failed, not a single one, sounded any differently after it has failed.

Comment: "My question is how do I gain access to the data in my failed HDD?". A data recovery service might be able to help you, but if the drive isn't being mounted by Windows, then your unlikely going to have any luck with that particular scamware software you mentioned.  The fact Windows is locking up means it's encountering I/O errors.  The time to have backed up your hdd was before it failed.

Comment: @Ramhound As I do monthly backup, my data is out dated by about half a month. I am trying to also avoid having to install all my applications and their settings.